# How can I rename an auto-named constraint when I get this error 15248?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

[image]

Method:

Open SSMS. Find table. Open constraints. Find constraint name. Right click, rename. Give new name.

EXPLODE. (well, it just fails, at least)

Comment: Did you try using `sp_rename` manually? `@objtype = 'OBJECT'` is correct, by the way.

Comment: Apparently ... It's a major crisis bug for MS: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=462046

Comment: @JonSeigel I did not, but I'm willing to give it a shot. We can chat in the heap or you can offer an answer? Marian in chat seems to think it's a true blue bug.

Comment: @JonSeigel I replicated same bug as in Connect :-). Been using a different schema, not dbo.

Comment: Ah, it probably doesn't specify the schema name in the `@objname` parameter.

Comment: I just noticed that the two constraint names in the message box don't match. Maybe it's a different problem. In any event, my answer should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) manually.

Note that this is fixed in SSMS 2012 (I don't remember if I have SP1 installed or not).

```
EXEC sp_rename
    @objname = N'[myschema].[DF__AccountTy__Allow__7E3AEC52]',
    @newname = N'DF_whatever',
    @objtype = 'OBJECT';
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have typo'd the constraint name, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not worried about the specific constraint name, but do I not need to supply the schema for the newname?

Comment: @jcolebrand: No, in fact I think you get an error if you try. You can't move the object to a different schema like this, which is why it's not required.